# Install Windows 7 on Google Cloud

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Im totally new to Google Cloud. I got free uses for some time from google.
I want to setup a lab. So I want to install Windows 7 on Google Cloud.
Thanks

Comment: Good luck, I hope you succeed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming and belongs to Google forums.

Comment: There are many questions on google cloud topic. you can find with flags. That's why I posted it, BTW thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image for Windows 7 is not available, you can create a custom image, upload it and then create an instance with that image, but honestly I would not follow this path if you have just started and you want only to run a Windows server.

So, if you don't really need Windows 7 for some reason and you want to run a Windows virtual machine the easiest thing to do is to create an instance using one of the [available images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support):

- Windows Server version 1709 Core for Containers (Beta)
- Windows Server version 1709 Core
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Core
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows Server 2016 Core
- Windows Server 2016

In order to do so go to the Console, enter in Compute Engine, VM instances, click on create instance, at this point from the tab that will be opened select the Windows image that you prefer and set up the machine as you like. Wait some minute and you will be able to connect to it through RDP.

Note that there is a [Quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-windows) in order to help you in the process.